# Primefaces Row-expansion not working

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am using primeface rowExpansion

```
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xl-1 col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1 text-right">Notes:</div>
                    <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">#{order.comments}</div>
                    <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">Requestor: #{order.requestorFullName}<h:outputText value="#{order.requestorFullName}"></h:outputText> 
                    <!-- <p:spacer width="5" height="5" />
                     <h:outputText value="#{order.currency}"></h:outputText> -->
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
                        Added:
                        <h:outputText value="#{order.requestedDate}">
                            <f:convertDateTime pattern="MM/dd/yy" />
                        </h:outputText>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </p:rowExpansion>
```

I have 3 records in data-table,when I am using the row-expansion,only the first row is showing the data rest 2 other rows are not showing the data ,the data is available in all the 3 records but it shows only in first row expansion in next 2 rows it is coming empty.

Can you help me on that

Thanks

Comment: Rowexpansion works in the showcase. Your code does not by a long shot resemble that. Please ceate a [mcve] and be way more specific instead of 'does not work'

Comment: Any at your browser log?

Comment: there are no error in browser log